# Get all the Payslips for a financial year in rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am generating payroll in my application. How to get all the payslips for a financial year(April,2013 to March,2014)

employee.rb

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  ..
  has_many :payslips, class_name: "Employee::Payslip", foreign_key: :employee_id
  ..
end
```

payslip.rb

```
class Employee::Payslip < ActiveRecord::Base
  ..
  belongs_to :employee
  ..
  validates_uniqueness_of :employee_id, :scope => [:month, :year]
end
```

I tried a lot but could not get it.

Comment: what are payslip attributes ?

Comment: payslip has employee_id and month and year.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to have :month and :year attributes on the payslip, so this ought to be as simple as:

```
Payslip.where(:year => 2013)
```

Edit: for the month range required ...

```
Payslip.where("((year = ? and month >= 4) or (year = ?+1 and month < 4))",2013, 2013)
```

That might not work well with some query optimisers, and it would have been better to represent the dates for the payslips as actual dates, not as a year and month number.

Comment: yeah but I need to get all the rows from april 2013 to mar 2014(financial year)

Comment: It's a shame that you've broken out month and year like that then, as it makes the process much more complex. But all you need here is  all the month numbers greater than or equal to 4 for the year of the fiscal year value, and all of the month numbers less than 4 for financial year + 1, right?

Answer (score 1):

Every active record object that u create will have field called as "created_at"... you can use this field and Time.now as limits to get your pay slips :)

```
Time.now
=> 2013-09-16 17:37:48 +0530

1.year.ago Time.now
=> 2012-09-16 17:37:49 +0530
```

If you use squeel, it will be a piece of cake to write the query.

```
PaySlip.where{created_at < Time.now and created_at > (1.year.ago Time.now)}
```

I am using the current year for this query...
if you want the payslip for a particular year, assign variables as such and place them in your query..

eg: `Time.new(2012)
=> 2012-01-01 00:00:00 +0530`

Check [this](https://github.com/ernie/squeel) for squeel...